# R Shiny: 'error cannot open the connection'

Tags: r, shiny, shiny-server

so I have a Shiny app where I'm trying to read in a user-identified input file.

Towards that end, my ui.R has the line `fileInput("predictor2", label = "Predictor Values")` and I try to read the file using the line `predictor <- read.delim("input$predictor2")` in my server.R file.

However, I get a message saying `Error: Cannot open the connection`. If I don't try to read in the file and use another matrix of values, the code works fine. Any advice for how to fix this problem or more detail that would be useful?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You code is looking for a file with the literal name `input$predictor2` which presumably does not exist. You first need to remove the quotes from around it, then add which column of the return actually has the path to the data, e.g.:

```
read.delim(input$predictor2$datapath)
```

See the help for `fileInput` for an example that checks to make sure something has been uploaded first.

Comment: Thanks Mark, that's perfect! I don't know how I didn't see that in the fileInput documentation earlier